# pyannote gives wrong results

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use `pyannote` for `speaker diarization`
and I'm getting wrong number of speakers.

Any example I tried I got wrong results.

For example:

- I used this youtube file:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2_ZZ2UpSzI
- I convert it to wav file with sample rate of 16000.

I run the following code:

```
from pyannote.audio import Pipeline

TEST_FILE = "example.wav"
MY_TOKEN = "..."
pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained("pyannote/speaker-diarization",
                                    use_auth_token=MY_TOKEN)

diarization = pipeline(TEST_FILE)
```

And I got the following diarization:
[image]

- The GT contains 4 speakers and not 2.

How can I tweak `pyannote` and get better results ?

Comment: I saw it also in some cases... waiting for answer too